# racket/gui: responding to double-click and hover events

Tags: user-interface, tooltip, racket

I'd like to be able to double-click an item in a `list-box%` to bring up an editor, or hover over things to display tooltips, but `mouse-event%` only covers `'enter'` and `'left-up` and I'd rather not have to start comparing event timestamps just to detect hover/double-click. `keymap%` looks like it might be able to handle the double-click but that seems to be designed for use with editors. Is there a way to connect a `keymap%` to other control types as well?

As for tooltips, it looks like they were going to implement them [a few years ago](https://github.com/racket/gui/issues/16) but there's no evidence that anything actually happened...

Answer (score 0):

1. For double click, [control-event%](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/control-event_.html) has a `list-box-dclick` type.
2. [tooltip-mixin](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui-widget-mixins/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gui-widget-mixins%2Fmain..rkt%29._tooltip-mixin%29%29) in `gui-widget-mixins` seems like what you need.